# Ionic 4 nav component WITHOUT Angular

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, web-component

Really loving the new ionic 4 components -- especially, NO Angular.

Issue though: I use the ion-nav like so:

```
navElRef.push('second-page')
```

The animation is not right. It seems I'm not setting the right parameters or classname or something. Is there docs/advice on how to use Ionic 4 nav WITHOUT angular?

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/core/src/components/nav

Comment: I get that. I’m already including this in my project. I’m just looking for clearer advice or documentation on how to use the nav in an angular free environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, after mucking around in the Ionic Framework 4 docs for two days, I see that there's basically nothing there to explain how to do this.

But, ... its actually not that hard to implement.

Got to: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav/. Then inspect the element of the phone example. Find the iframe in the elements tab of Chrome dev tools (or whatever you use). Copy that src and open it in a new browser tab. Now, you can see a working example that uses no framework. You can just copy the HTML src and create your own index.html from that and it should work.

The list of making the ion-nav work is this:

- Make sure to have class="plt-desktop ios" mode="ios" attrs in HTML tag (or whatever os you want)
- Make sure to have included js and CSS: 'https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.11/dist/ionic.js' and 'https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.bundle.css' in HTML file
- Make sure the ion-nav is wrapped inside of the ion-app tag.
- add root="page-one" attr to your ion-nav signifying what web component you want to be initially shown. "page-one" is the name of your component as defined by window.customElements.define -- whatever you want it to be.
- You can use an ion-nav-push component to push another page onto the nav component. But, more likely, you'll be using a router (React, Page, etc, etc) to handle this. In your specific router solution instigate the page navigation by calling the push method on the ion-nav element: something like:

  document.querySelector('ion-nav').push('page-two')

You can read more about calling the navigation methods here:  https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav/

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="plt-desktop ios" mode="ios">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nav</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.11/dist/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/overrides.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.bundle.css">
  <script>
    class PageOne extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
          <ion-header translucent>
            <ion-toolbar>
              <ion-title>Page One</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
          </ion-header>
          <ion-content padding fullscreen>
            <h1>Page One</h1>
            <ion-nav-push component="page-two">
              <ion-button class="next">Go to Page Two</ion-button>
            </ion-nav-push>
          </ion-content>
        `;
      }
    }
    class PageTwo extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
          <ion-header translucent>
            <ion-toolbar>
              <ion-buttons slot="start">
                <ion-back-button text="Page One"></ion-back-button>
              </ion-buttons>
              <ion-title>Page Two</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
          </ion-header>
          <ion-content padding fullscreen>
            <h1>Page Two</h1>
            <div>
              <ion-nav-push component="page-three">
                <ion-button class="next">Go to Page Three</ion-button>
              </ion-nav-push>
            </div>
          </ion-content>
        `;
      }
    }
    class PageThree extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
          <ion-header translucent>
            <ion-toolbar>
              <ion-buttons slot="start">
                <ion-back-button text="Page Two"></ion-back-button>
              </ion-buttons>
              <ion-title>Page Three</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
          </ion-header>
          <ion-content padding fullscreen>
            <h1>Page Three</h1>
          </ion-content>
        `;
      }
    }
    customElements.define('page-one', PageOne);
    customElements.define('page-two', PageTwo);
    customElements.define('page-three', PageThree);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-nav root="page-one"></ion-nav>
  </ion-app>
  <style>
    ion-toolbar {
      --background: white;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how to navigate using `ion-router` in the above code?